# How do I set the inputBuffer of an akka stream publisher?

Tags: stream, akka

I'm using Akka streams in a context where sinks for a single source will come and go. For this reason I'm creating a publisher from a source and attaching subscribers as the need arise:

```
val publisher= mySource.runWith(Sink.publisher(true))
```

with

```
publisher.subscribe(subscriber1)// There will be others
```

Some of the subscribers will be faster than others and I'd like to allow the faster ones to go ahead independently of the slowest, at least to the extend permitted by the input buffer of the publisher. This buffer is described by the comment on the *Sink.publisher(true)* method:

> If `fanout` is `true`, the materialized `Publisher` will support multiple `Subscriber`s and the size of the `inputBuffer` configured for this stage becomes the maximum number of elements that the fastest [[org.reactivestreams.Subscriber]] can be ahead of the slowest one before slowing the processing down due to back pressure.

My problem is that I don't know how to set this inputBuffer value "for this stage". The closest I have seen is described in the Dropping Broadcast section of [this article](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka-stream-and-http-experimental/1.0-M2/scala/stream-cookbook.html) but this seems to insist on the use of the Flow DSL. I believe that I can't use the DSL because of my need to continually attach new Subscribers.

As a result, my overall stream rate is held back by the slowest subscriber. A related aspect of what I am trying to do relates to making sure the different subscribers are running on different threads (without creating explicit actors as subscribers).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'd look something like (for Akka Streams 2.0.1):

```
Sink.asPublisher(true).addAttributes(Attributes.inputBuffer(initialSize, maxSize))
```